# Why would I have high CPU usage (single core) when running glxgears on a GPU?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, cpu, gpu

When running glxgears (or any graphically intensive application) on linux I see 100% utilization of a single cpu core, even though I've confirmed it is using my Nvidia GPU as the renderer.  Is that expected?

**My Machine**

```
$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Kernel: 4.15.0-38-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.4.6 (Gtk 3.18.9) Distro: Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya
Machine:   System: Dell (portable) product: Precision 5520
           Mobo: Dell model: 04GFKY v: A00 Bios: Dell v: 1.5.0 date: 08/30/2017
CPU:       Quad core Intel Xeon E3-1505M v6 (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 24000
           clock speeds: max: 4000 MHz 1: 1727 MHz 2: 1417 MHz 3: 1354 MHz 4: 1510 MHz 5: 949 MHz 6: 1430 MHz
           7: 1283 MHz 8: 1440 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel HD Graphics P630 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM107GLM [Quadro M1200 Mobile] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 driver: nvidia Resolution: 3440x1440@49.99hz
           GLX Renderer: Quadro M1200/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.130 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

I have a somewhat uncommon setup in that I'm using linux on a laptop with Nvidia Optimus (Intel integrated graphics + discrete Nvidia mobile GPU).  However I've configured linux to use the dedicated Nvidia GPU using `nvidia-prime` and verified the configuration (the `inxi` output above also reports the Nvidia card/driver being used as the graphics renderer).

**Test**

I start glxgears:

```
$ glxgears -info
GL_RENDERER   = Quadro M1200/PCIe/SSE2
GL_VERSION    = 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.130
GL_VENDOR     = NVIDIA Corporation
```

and in `htop` I see:

[image]

I also ran `oprofile` to get a report of what my CPU was doing, which gave me:

```
CPU: Intel Architectural Perfmon, speed 4000 MHz (estimated)
Counted CPU_CLK_UNHALTED events (Clock cycles when not halted) with a unit mask of 0x00 (No unit mask) count 100000
CPU_CLK_UNHALT...|
  samples|      %|
------------------
  4232537 100.000 glxgears
        CPU_CLK_UNHALT...|
          samples|      %|
        ------------------
          3155713 74.5584 kallsyms
           523169 12.3606 libnvidia-glcore.so.384.130
           332903  7.8653 libc-2.23.so
           177315  4.1893 libGL.so.384.130
            27398  0.6473 .glxj5h8n
             3605  0.0852 libxcb.so.1.1.0
             3396  0.0802 libX11.so.6.3.0
             3273  0.0773 libm-2.23.so
             2594  0.0613 glxgears
             1218  0.0288 [vdso] (tgid:10292 range:0x7ffc294d2000-0x7ffc294d3fff)
              706  0.0167 .glWqJoPX
              682  0.0161 libXext.so.6.4.0
              366  0.0086 .glhBcsou
               68  0.0016 snd_usb_audio
               51  0.0012 nvidia
               41 9.7e-04 iwlwifi
               18 4.3e-04 kvm
               15 3.5e-04 x86_pkg_temp_thermal
                2 4.7e-05 hid
                2 4.7e-05 mac80211
                2 4.7e-05 nvidia_uvm
```

Based on that glxgears is definitely using the nvidia backend so I'm confused why a pure graphics application, using a gpu, would also have high single core cpu usage?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a linux expert, but *kallsyms* is the kernel, and I see google chatter about high CPU in kernel/kallsyms on laptops where there is/was a kernel bug related to USB dynamic power management (see for example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044872/ubuntu-16-04-kworker-using-high-cpu-constantly).